# Can we combine YOLOv5 object detection model with anomaly detection?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolov5

I am working on a helmet detection model using yolov5, I need to detect only safety helmets as **helmet** class and other helmets(bike helmets, cricket helmets, no helmets) as **no helmet** class.
So Is there any way to perform object detection on **no helmet** class without labeling the data?
Can we perform anomaly detection on such kind of dataset?

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSJHu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOLO as any other object detection model will output those things, that you will label - if you label only safety helmets, well trained model will try to give you only safety helmets, and ignore all other kind of helmets (or heads without helmets). If you want to detect "no helmets", you will need to label another class "no helmets".

Sure it's possible to use anomaly detection here (e.g. simple encoder-decoder architecture) above detections (input of anomaly detection model will be output, bounding box, of YOLO). Probably results will be better, but this solution will be more resource-intensive (run two models vs one).

Comment: Thank you, Can you please explain in detail how can I achieve this. As you said input of the anomaly detection model would be the output of YOLO but I have only Helmet labeled data I haven't labeled no helmet data, so do we need no helmet labeled data?

Comment: You can take a look at open-source solutions like [these](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/anomalib) or [these](https://medium.com/linkedai/anomaly-detection-production-line-b8340e1eca43).

You can just find resources like "anomaly detection in computer vision"